# Is it possible to reuse a CryptVerifySignature() hash object?

Tags: c, cryptoapi

MSDN says that after `CryptVerifySignature()` you cannot reuse `HCRYPTHASH` object to try hashing more data, instead it says you need to recreate it with `CryptDestroyHash()` and `CryptCreateHash()`. *Reusing really fails.*

**Anyone is familiar with a hack that can save these calls, or it is really impossible?**

Comment: **Creating and destroying the `HCRYPTHASH` is a 20 cycle operation on my machine.** It's not that expensive. It would be nice to reuse but it does keep internal state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the `HCRYPTHASH` data structure is more flexible than just being used to call with `CryptVerifySignature()`.  It's designed to operate on a (possibly discontinuous) stream of data (via `CryptHashData()`), which means it stores some state within it on the hash's current values.  Therefore, once you've used it on a stream (even partial) the state is irrevocably altered, so you can't use it on another stream.

I guess they could've provided a `reset` function for the `HCRYPTHASH` structure... but they didn't!